# What does `exec "$@"` do?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, exec

I've been seeing this in a lot of `docker-entrypoint.sh` scripts recently, and can't find an explanation online. My first thoughts are that it is something to do with signaling but that's a pretty wild guess.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I didn't add docker-entrypoint parts to my search queries! If a mod wants to lock/delete this they can, just felt it was more appropriate to ask here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `"$@"` bit will expand to the list of positional parameters (usually the command line arguments), individually quoted to avoid word splitting and filename generation ("globbing").

The `exec` will replace the current process with the process resulting from executing its argument.

In short, `exec "$@"` will run the command given by the command line parameters in such a way that the current process is replaced by it (if the `exec` is able to execute the command at all).

Comment: So it's a way of hot-swapping the purpose of a process? So instead of allowing it to die, we just repurpose it for something else?

Comment: @JohnVonNeumann Yes, and it makes the signal handling easier to handle as Stephen Kitt wrote in his answer.

Comment: It's funny, I'm studying my Linux Foundation SysAdmin atm and I literally just got to a section describing this procedure. You made it a lot easier to understand. I'd never really thought of running bash commands as spawning new processes, dunno what I did think, but it hadn't occurred that that's the way it works.

Comment: @JohnVonNeumann Yes, that's what happens in shell scripts, except for when executing built-in commands such as `printf` and `true` etc. (unless the external version of these are explicitly used).

Answer (score 11):

[Two](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/467003/86440) [other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/467002/86440) answers explain what `exec "$@"` does. [This answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32261019/4500798) explains why it’s important for Docker, and as you surmise, it does have to do with signals:

> This is important in Docker for signals to be proxied correctly. For example, if Redis was started without `exec`, it will not receive a `SIGTERM` upon `docker stop` and will not get a chance to shutdown cleanly. In some cases, this can lead to data loss or zombie processes.
>
> If you do start child processes (i.e. don't use `exec`), the parent process becomes responsible for handling and forwarding signals as appropriate. This is one of the reasons it's best to use `supervisord` or similar when running multiple processes in a container, as it will forward signals appropriately.

Answer (score 9):

`"$@"` in Bourne-like shells, in list contexts expands to all the positional parameters as separate arguments.

In a script, initially, the positional parameters are the arguments that the script itself received.

`exec` is to run a command in the same process as the shell. That's the last command a script will execute because after that, the process will be running another command than the shell.

So if your script is

```
#! /bin/sh -
exec "$@"
```

And you call your script using a shell command line like:

```
/path/to/your-script 'echo' "some  test" 'x y'
```

It will call `exec` with `echo`, `some  test`, and `x y` as arguments which will execute `echo` (in most `sh` implementations, `/bin/echo` as opposed to the `echo` shell builtin) in the same process that was previously running the shell interpreting your script with `some  test` and `x y` as arguments.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, basically, you can use it to say, run a script multiple times with a variety of arguments? Or have I completely missed it?